# problems with libraries in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jena, agents-jade

The libraries are located in the project in this way

[image]

The makefile looks like this

[image]

When I try to call make compile I get the following errors from both libraries
[image]
At the same time, when navigating through an instance of these libraries, I am transported to their description in the library, so I do not understand what is wrong

Comment: `import jade....` isn't referring to anything from Jena.

Comment: "from both libraries"
The following errors are of the same type with JENA, they are not in the screenshot

Comment: src\Agentes\OntologyParser.java:4: error: package org.apache.jena.query does not exist
import org.apache.jena.query.*;

src\Agentes\OntologyParser.java:5: error: package org.apache.jena.rdf.model does not exist
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.*;

Comment: For Java projects consider using a proper build tool like [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org) to manage project structure and dependencies following standard Java conventions rather than rolling your own approach

Comment: Make sure you've added a library to the module dependencies. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-a-project-library .

Comment: @EgorKlepikov Thanks, I added a library. But it didn't help to solve the problem
Я не понимаю, почему идея считает, что пэкэйдж не существует, он есть в jarнике jade

Comment: judging by the screen, you use `:` in classpach, you should use `;` according to java help `-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>A ; separated list of directories`

Comment: You can add the jade library and its dependencies properly through Maven. 
[Jade maven repo](https://jade-project.gitlab.io/page/download/)